# Returning object with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, class, shared-ptr

Hey so I'm writing a function that will return the correct class if the name is found. In the case that I don't find a class what and how should I return.

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<myClass>> myClasses;

class myClass{
    std::string name = "bob";
    myClass();
};

std::shared_ptr<myClass> getMyClass(const std::string _name){
    for (auto& x : myClasses){
        if (x->name == _name){
            return x;
        }
    }
    // Else return nullptr???
    return std::make_shared<myClass>(nullptr);
}
```

Before I had tried to return by myClass& but that seems to cause me more problems when trying to return null. I am trying to get it to the point where I can call my `getMyClass` function and It will return the class if found and nothing otherwise.

Comment: Returning a default constructed `std::shared_ptr` would be a way to return a null-pointer. That seems reasonable enough to me, what is your problem with that?

Comment: @UnholySheep What like `return std::make_shared<myClass>();` ? That gives me compiler errors about no matching function for std::construct_at

Comment: No, just `return std::shared_ptr<myClass>();`. Or even simpler `return {};`. Even `return nullptr;` should work

Comment: @UnholySheep Wow i feel stupid, that's really helped, thanks;

Comment: Option 1: `std::optional`.  Option 2:  `std::shared_ptr<myClass>{}`.  Option 3:  `throw` an exception (if such is really an exceptional situation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is okay for a `shared_ptr<T>` to be null.

I think the most idiomatic way to return one would be

```
return {};
```

from within a function that returns a shared pointer to some type. Returning curly braces like this means to return a "default constructed" object. In this case it will be a shared pointer with `nullptr` as its raw pointer member.